# How to avoid using certificate when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I would like to avoid using certificate for authentication when opening some sites using chrome. However I would not like to remove these certificates as I would like to continue using these certificates through internet explorer.

Any possibilities? I searched the web but could not get any answer that suits my requirement.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

In tools menu, under preferences and "under the hood"/"advanced options" tab, at the bottom you can manage certificates.

Comment: I need an option which disables the use of IE certificates or precisely Internet options certificates from Chrome...